Unexplainable slowness on my Win10 PC
I am running Win10 Pro 22H2 19045.2364. It's normally a fast machine, and you can see my full specs down below. But every 2-5 days, everything goes SLOW and SLUGGISH, with no indications why. In fact, right now it is very slow again, so I captured some stats:


You can see that my resource consumption is low. No red flags, nothing.
Here are the specific symptoms, and what I mean by slow:

Scrolling up and down in any text editor or Chrome is slow/choppy/sluggish
Alt-Tabbing around between open programs is slow/sluggish
Working in VSCode or Notepad++, doing anything at all, is slow/choppy/sluggish

I don't have anything massive/heavy running. No video editing, no bitcoin mining, no graphics rendering. And even if I did have something like that, it would show up in my performance monitors displayed above.
Here is what I do have running:

VSCode (1 instance)
Chrome (8 tabs open, and none doing anything crazy)
HeidiSQL
Postman
Outlook 365
Filezilla
Windows paint (2 instances)

I just ran latest available MalwareBytes (as of 4/12/2024) and it found exactly 0 evidences of malware.
The ONLY solution I have found to this slowness to to reboot my machine. After I do that, my PC runs FAST for 2-5 days until the slowness hits again. I have no idea what causes this or what conditions enable it to begin. It just suddenly goes slow, and remains slow forever until I do a full reboot. After a reboot it's rare for the slowness to resume on the same day, maybe that has never happened. But as sure as death and taxes, the slowness resumes within 2-5 days.
I can't think of any common thread. Opening a certain program, performing a certain task, etc. The slowness comes on randomly and unexpectedly, never as a result of doing some particular thing, as far as I can tell.
Here are my specs:
Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz   2.10 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB (63.8 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Before the onset of the dreaded slowness, everything is lightning fast, regardless of how many apps I have open. I can be running TONS of apps, and everything is fast. When the slowness inevitably begins, I can close all my apps, and reopen nothing but Notepad - and it's still slow. I don't think the slowness is related to any open apps or even a combination of apps.
I have been living with this for about 2 years and it's driving me crazy. I am hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance.

just out of curiosity, does killing your desktop explorer process cause it to get "fast" again? have you checked your system temps? I know you mentioned malwarebytes on-demand scanning, but do you have an "active" anti-malware application (one that monitors all reads/writes, network, etc)? the issue is clearly not with resource shortfalls. do you have lots of monitors or use very high resolutions?

Frank, I have always had active/realtime virus scanners turned off, and I turned off Windows Defender this morning.

@HerrimanCoder, then look for malware on your machine. E.G., a crypto miner might be hiding itself. Also. look at the Details tab of Task Manager and sort on I/O Reads, on I/O Writes as well as on CPU.

DrMoishe: I did a full malware scan, which would have found malware like a crypto miner. John: I already did a complete offline scan with MalwareBytes, which is better than windows defender.

Frank: The slowness is happening again. I killed all windows explorer processes and the slowness remained. Disk usage across all disks seems nominal.
